# making json structure by code in android

Tags: android, json

I have the following json structure which i need to send it to server using post request. Please help in making the same structure by code in android.
The json structure is as follows :

```
{
  "
    }
}
```

Since i am newbie to android so please help.

Comment: Well that is one right path. Here is another, http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Comment: Can you help  me move forward in my right path ?

Comment: Sure, keep following that path. Post here when you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Use the JSONObject class in android, here is an example:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
JSONObject cardAcceptorkey = new JSONObject();
try {

    //CREATE cardAcceptorkey object
    cardAcceptorkey.put("id","CA-IDCode");
    cardAcceptorkey.put("name","USA");
    ...

    //CREATE object
    object.put("AuditNumber", "451035adss");
    object.put("cardAcceptorkey", cardAcceptorkey);
    ...

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

More info: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidJSON/article.html

Comment: can you explain how to move forward in this structure?

Comment: Just put all the properties in the JSONObject, creating JSONObject s for every { } in the String and nesting them. Another approach would be to use your string as template. I assume is JSONArray containing several JSONObject items, so Template = [THE_STRING_YOU_PASTED], and then simply do JSONArray array = new JSONArray(Template); You can do the same with JSONObject, just make sure it is a JSONObject String